# How can i remove empty space after header on next page in fancy hdr?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

[image]

Here is my code...

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}  
\usepackage{fontspec}  
\usepackage{arydshln}  
\usepackage[a4paper, left=0.5cm,  
 right=0.5cm,top=0.3cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{dashrule}  
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\setmainfont{Arial}  
\setlength{\headheight}{86pt}  
\setlength{\footskip}{17pt}  
\setlength{\headsep}{8pt}  
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}  
\setlength\dashlinedash{5pt}  
\setlength\dashlinegap{6pt}  
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.2pt}  
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}  
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}  
\renewcommand\footrule{\hdashrule{20.2cm}{1pt}{5pt}}  
\chead{\empty}  
\lhead{\begin{tabular}{l}  
\directlua{img.write(img.new({  
 filename="C:/Users/ms/Desktop/diagnostyk_dokumenty/diagnostyk.pdf" ,  
 height="1cm"}))}\\\hdashline  
\textbf{REJESTRACJA: Pn.-Pt. 8.00-18.00, tel.: 222 422 22 22, 22 22 22  
 07~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}\\  
Informacja: L. Willsoni - tel.: 603 603 882 W. Walker - tel. 604 141  
 797\\\hdashline  
\end{tabular}}  
\rhead{\textbf{Zielona Pola}\hspace{89pt}\textbf{Zielona Pola}\\  
\textbf{ul. Mandy 27}\hspace{85pt}\textbf{ul. Mazów 42}\\  
Filia\hspace{25pt}Budynek AAAAAAAAA IIIp.\\}  
\lfoot{\bfseries{\large{www.diagnostyk.de ~~\bullet~~~MAMMOGRAFIA  
 ~~\bullet~~~USG~ \bullet~~~RTG ~\bullet~~~USG-DOPPLER  
 ~~\bullet~~www.diagnostyk.de}}}  
\cfoot{\empty}  
\rfoot{\empty}  
\begin{document}  

how can i set empty page?\\  


\newpage  
\thispagestyle{empty}  
\lipsum  
\end{document}
```

My question is how can i remove  this empty space ?

Comment: The `\headheight` of 86pt (about 3cm) is what you're seeing here, even if a running head is omitted.

Comment: so what can i do ? can you give me a advise ?